# Where can I find documentation about the options that can be set in rabbitmq.conf?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I run RabbitMQ in a Kubernetes cluster and use a configuration file to configure some settings:

> /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

Right now the only option is:

> management.path_prefix = /prefix

I want to add a time-to-live for the messages in the queue, but can't find how to do so via rabbitmq.conf.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-items) you can find most of the configuration parameters defined in `rabbitmq.conf`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know which one configures the amount of time a message is allowed to exist in the RabbitMQ queue?

Comment: I guess you mean the expiration settings on queue level. If that is so, then there is an official docs on that as well : https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

Comment: I think I mean on message level not queue level? I noticed that a message stayed in the queue over the weekend (I deleted my Celery workers during the weekend so it wasn't processed) and I don't want that to happen. I want messages in RabbitMQ deleted after about 10 minutes. In the link you sent "message-ttl" is set for this purpose. But when I tried setting it in rabbitmq.conf, it said that it wasn't recognized.